# Prevent IPython from displaying long lists one element per line

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

In Jupyter notebooks, or in IPython, long lists are displayed one element per line. How do I display them on a single line? I don't mind if the line wraps.

In the following example, I'd like the 3rd list to be shown as a "row", not as a "column".

```
In [1]: [list(range(n)) for n in range(10,40,10)]
Out[1]: 
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7,
  8,
  9,
  10,
  11,
  12,
  13,
  14,
  15,
  16,
  17,
  18,
  19,
  20,
  21,
  22,
  23,
  24,
  25,
  26,
  27,
  28,
  29]]
```

The output I am looking for is the following or similar:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]
```

My goal is to make the output easier to read for humans.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use

```
A = [list(range(n)) for n in range(10,40,10)]

for i in A:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer suggested you can use print(stuff) to avoid that behaviour. But print does not share the object notation of display(stuff), so you'd need to format your own output.

Alternatively, if you really want to use display(), i could recommend my lazy method of just displaying the lists string representation:

```
In [1]: [str(list(range(n))) for n in range(10,40,10)]
```

outputs almost what you want

```
Out[1]: ['[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]',
'[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]',
'[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]']
```